# Jquery: How to clear cache or get updated JSONP from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I have a ajax call as shown below in an asp.net application

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: plugin.settings.resourceurl + plugin.settings.datap,
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'headerfooter',
    contentType: 'application/javascript',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(retresult) {
        // console.log(retresult);

    },
    error: function(e) {
        // console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

The ajax call returns chunck of data from JSONP file, this ajax call is frequently called as it is contained in the master page, so its cached. The JSONP file in server will be modified in server in few occasions, this change in JSONP file is reflected in application only after manually clearing browser cache. I want the application to reflect the updates without removing cache.

I tried the below code

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:'http://localhost/api',
    dataType:'json',
    cache:true,
    ifModified:true,
    success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
        console.debug(jqXHR.status+':'+textStatus);
        console.debug(data); // On repeated request returns `undefined`
    }
});
```

Here jqXHR.status tells if the JSONP file was modified with 200 and 304 if not, but everytime i run the code it gives 200.
Am i doing it right? or is there a better way to achieve it.

Comment: You know you're setting `cache: true`, right? Tried changing it to `false`?

Comment: side-note, the following options in your ajax request are being ignored because this is a jsonp request: `type, contentType, async, error`

Comment: All thanks for the reply, @RoryMcCrossan yes i want to cache and i have mentioned it in the question. I want the caching available, unless there is a change in the JSONP file, the cache timeout is set to 1 week.

Answer (score 1):

just add a random token to create a unique uncached uri:

```
url: plugin.settings.resourceurl + plugin.settings.datap + '?t=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
```

respectively:

```
url:'http://localhost/api'+ '?t=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
```

also, you might want to set `cache: false` in your ajax settings :)

Comment: if i give unique uri, and if the JSONP file has not changed, then JSONP file will be pulled from server everytime, this will choke the server, so i want the script to get the JSONP file only if it is changed, get cached file if it is not.

Comment: implement this logic in the server side logic then

Answer (score 0):

304 will not be returned in this case since you are using a random callback . caching is url specific, hence the random callback keeps changing the url